# monitor http request from non-browser

Tags: http, httprequest, monitoring

I want to monitor HTTP request generated out of an exe. Is there any tool that can help me?

Actually, an exe would call my ASP.NET web page to register a user. The exe constructs the POST data request and calls my page. When the request reaches my web page, I don't see any data. I want to monitor the Request object and the traffic to find the reality.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: I tired Fiddler but it's able to monitor only requests generated from browser

Comment: Not quite true, I believe it can monitor any request that uses the windows internet support, so it won't catch requests implemented on top of sockets (can someone confirm this?). Also it can't catch requests to localhost - an easy workaround is requesting to your computer name.

Comment: It's able to monitor only IE requests for my configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I use [httpdebugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com/); It is the best for me because it can monitor `http` requests of java applications which sent by `JVM`.

Comment: please share the open source tools.

Answer (score 2):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a nice tool to do just what you're asking.  It will record all network data sent across a network interface so you can see exactly what's being sent with your POST request.  The interface can be a little overpowering, but works well.

Comment: I tried WireShark but Im not able to find the needed POST request. This issue occurs with SI environment. The same code works good with UAT environment. I guess it has something to do with network.  I will follow this with my network guys. 
Thanks for your input. Ananth

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is another program that I'd suggest for doing such monitoring besides [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).